# Как проверить включен ли режим разработчика в Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как можно програмно в расширении проверить включен ли у пользователя режим разработчика? С помощью приватного API делается вот так:

```
chrome.developerPrivate.getProfileConfiguration((conf) => {
    if (conf.inDeveloperMode) {/* ... */}
});
```

Но это API не доступно для самого расширения.

Comment: А какая цель ставится?

Comment: Пользователю расширения нужно показать ссылку. Если у него включен режим разработчика - одну, иначе - другую.

Comment: Я к тому, что возможно можно что-нибудь придумать в качестве альтернативы, но информации о ссылках мало. Тем не менее ответ оставлен.

Comment: `chrome://version/` по этому адресу есть параметр `Командная строка`. В этой строке указаны флаги которые были использованы при запуске хрома. (Возможно сможете как-то применить это)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что это возможно.

Но можно воспользоваться функцией `chrome.management.getSelf`, которая в качестве результата возвращает объект с информацией о расширении.

Для данной задачи можно использовать свойство `installType`, которое указывает на то, как было установленно расширение:

> How the extension was installed. One of
>
> - admin: The extension was installed because of an administrative policy,
> - development: The extension was loaded unpacked in developer mode,
> - normal: The extension was installed normally via a .crx file,
> - sideload: The extension was installed by other software on the machine,
> - other: The extension was installed by other means.

Данная функция не требует указания `management` в `permissions`.

---

```
chrome.management.getSelf(function (result) {

    if (result["installType"] == "development") {

        console.log("Yeah!");
    }
});
```

Если `installType` равно `development`, то можно сделать предположение, что `Developer Mode` включен.

---

Однако результат не гарантирует того, что в данный момент `Develope Mode` включен.

Еще можно использовать эту функцию совместно с событием `chrome.runtime.onInstalled`, которое сработает при установки расширения, тогда можно знать наверняка, включен `Developer Mode` **на момент установки** или нет.

---

[chrome.management.getSelf](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getSelf) | [chrome.runtime.onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled)